# What do we only care about $\alpha=1$ for unit roots?

Tags: time-series, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

https://www.machinelearningplus.com/time-series/augmented-dickey-fuller-test/

In 2), why do we only care about $\alpha=1$ to get a unit root. I guess if $\alpha<1$ we have some mean reversion, but why dont we care about $\alpha>1$?

Comment: [FYI](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151703/explosive-processes-non-stationarity-and-unit-roots-how-to-distinguish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that "we don't care". Mathematically, it is not possible to test the null hypothesis $\alpha > 1$, i.e. the model is explosive, against the alternative, say, $\alpha \leq 1$.

One can characterize the distribution of, say, the Dickey-Fuller-type $t$-statistic for each $\alpha > 1$. The limit distribution is a Cauchy distribution. However, the normalizing factor of the statistic depends on $\alpha$, in contrast to the stationary ($|\alpha| < 1$) case.

Comment: The null hypothesis of the ADF test is presence of unit root, $\alpha=1$. The distribution of the test statistic under the null does not change if we consider alternative $\alpha<1$ or $\alpha>1$. Why should we care about the distribution of the test statistic under the alternative (except for power analysis)? Is it probably difficult to define the $p$-value for the two-sided alternative?

Comment: "except for power analysis"---power is the only thing that matters, for any test. Unit roots tests already have low power against one-sided stationary alternative. A two-sided test would have even lower power. (p-values are not an issue, they're easily obtainable.)

Comment: It's also not set in stone that one must take $\alpha = 1$ as the null. Tests where $\alpha = 1$ is the alternative, like KPSS, exists because power issues with unit root tests. For the explosive case, such complementary test would not be possible.

Comment: I understand the part of the question *but why dont we care about $\alpha>1$* as considering that as the alternative, not the null. As far as I understand from your comment, technically this would not be a problem, just as well as $H_1\colon \alpha\neq 1$?

Comment: And now I realize I misread your post initially. I was thinking of $H_0\colon\alpha=1$ and considering different alternatives, while you were focusing on $H_0\colon\alpha>1$.